# Chrome RE-DIRECT without Opening New Window or Tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, redirect

Need to get Chrome to RE-DIRECT in the CURRENT TAB-WINDOW and NOT OPEN a New Tab-Window for the URL Re-Direct.

Any clues?

The Code - but opens the RE-DIRECT URL in another Tab-Window:

Private Chrome As Intent
   Chrome.Initialize(Chrome.ACTION_VIEW,"http://www.youtube.com")
   Chrome.SetComponent("com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main")
   StartActivity(Chrome)

I have an idea!!!

Is there ANY WAY to CLOSE CURRENT TAB? So nevermind Chrome opens New Tab.

Comment: Redirects don't open in new tabs by default.  This can't be answered without your current code.

Comment: Hi Gerald,

Is there any way to CLOSE A TAB in Chrome?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are some tips about asking questions on SO. The code you posted needs reformatting (basically adding 4 spaces before each line of code)

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of redirecting the page using Javascript is by changing window.location:

```
window.location="http://example.com"
```